# NullPointerException Getting swdl port

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception, wsdl

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to connect with a WSDL.

When I test the web service it works perfectly. Also, the WSDL route is correct.

Here is the servlet who is calling the WS.

```
@WebServlet(name = "ValidationServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ValidationServlet"})
public class requestValidationServlet extends HttpServlet {

@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/Pagos/PagosService?WSDL")
private PagosService_Service service;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    User user = new User()
    user.setName((String) request.getAttribute("name"));
    user.setLastName((String) request.getAttribute("lastname"));

    String validate = validation(user.getName(), user.getLastName());

}
private int validation(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String lastname, java.lang.String identification, java.lang.String mail, java.lang.String nit, int price) {
    org.pagos.service.PagosService port = service.getPagosServicePort();
    return port.validation(name, lastname, identification, mail, nit, price);
}
}
```

I'm getting the error when the service tries to get the port: `service.getPagosServicePort()`.

And the error is this:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[ValidationServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet ValidationServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException


at com.clinimonse.servlets.requestValidationServlet.validation(requestValidationServlet.java:113)
    at com.clinimonse.servlets.requestValidationServlet.doPost(requestValidationServlet.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It's not, I know what is a null Exception, the point is I don't know why is null when the servlet is trying to get the port of the web service.

Comment: your service field is null. So ehatever DI container you use, it is not set up correctly.

Comment: I think so, the stranger thing is, I tested it in another project and it works perfectly.